# getting instagram access token

Tags: python, instagram, python-requests

How to get an access token from just Python?

My code is like this:

```
import bottle_session
import bottle
import cgi,os
from bottle import route, redirect, post, run, request
from instagram import client, subscriptions
import urllib
from pygeocoder import Geocoder

results = Geocoder.geocode("University of Santo Tomas,Manila,Philippines")
print(results[0].coordinates)

latitude=results[0].latitude
longitude=results[0].longitude 

CONFIG = {
    'client_id': '',
    'client_secret': '',
    'redirect_uri': 'localhost:8515/oauth_callback'
}

unauthenticated_api = client.InstagramAPI(**CONFIG)
  
url = unauthenticated_api.get_authorize_url(scope=["likes","comments"])
   
code = request.GET.get("code")
print "CODE:" + str(code)

access_token, user_info = unauthenticated_api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code)
print "access token= " + access_token
print access_token

api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
session['access_token']=access_token
```

Comment: Swearing at your code via `print` statements usually doesn't help me debug the problem ;) Though I guess it relieves some stress.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i do same things in Django:

```
SCOPE = ('basic', 'comments', 'relationships', 'likes')


def get_api(access_token=None):
    if access_token is not None:
        # authenticated api
        return InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
    else:
        # unauthenticated api
        return InstagramAPI(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                            redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL)


def logout(request):
    try:
        del request.session['token']
        del request.session['instagram_user']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return redirect(REDIRECT_URL)


def signin(request):
    api = get_api()
    redirect_uri = api.get_authorize_login_url(scope=SCOPE)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_uri)

# Redirect url goes here
def instagram(request):
    template = 'account/instagram.html'
    access_token = request.session.get('token')
    instagram_user = request.session.get('instagram_user')

    if not access_token:
        code = request.GET.get("code")

        if not code:
            t = loader.get_template(template)
            c = RequestContext(request, {})
            return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

        unauthenticated_api = get_api()
        access_token, instagram_user = (
            unauthenticated_api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code))
        request.session['token'] = access_token
        request.session['instagram_user'] = instagram_user
        if not access_token:
            return HttpResponse('Could not get access token')

    api = get_api(access_token)
    instagram_user = api.user(instagram_user['id'])

    t = loader.get_template(template)
    c = RequestContext(request, {'insta_user': instagram_user})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: do the users need to authorize the app  ? Because I need to develop a python program without going to the browser just to get the access token

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do in your app. You can do some api requests without authenticating api.

`api = InstagramAPI(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)`
`content, next_url = api.tag_recent_media(count=10, tag_name=tag)`

Comment: How can you authorise users without going to browser?

Comment: I need to authorize users? how can I get  an access token?

Comment: U get an access token only after user is authorized. U can only authorize user by redirecting him to instagram.com in browser.

Comment: Oh okay, Is it much better if i would use a web app instead?

Comment: Yep. You certainly should.

Comment: I have a problem getting the code here? its always empty